# Array of Decodable type is not decodable

Tags: swift, types, decodable

If we have a type `Foo: Decodable` how can we make `Array<Foo>` decodable?

Would I have to create another type `Foos: Decodable` ?

If so how would this work?

---

I'm seeing the issue here

```
func exampleMethod<T:Decodable>(type: T) { }

// Argument type 'Array<Foo>.Type' does not conform to expected type 'Decodable'
exampleMethod(type: [Foo].self)
```

Comment: Your method is waiting for an instance and you are trying to pass the type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use this:

`let res = JSONDecoder().decode([Foo].self, data)`

for your case:

`exampleMethod(type: [Foo()])`

Regarding `exampleMethod` signature you should write an array. Not a type of array.

Comment: Hi, this does work but I'm getting an error when I create a method with a generic parameter of type <T:Decodable>. I updated my question with an example

Comment: Okay, thank you this made me realize its an issue with me using generics incorrectly. Can you just write that down in your question, I will mark it as correct. I was passing in the type but it was actually expecting a value.

Answer (score 0):

If `Foo` conforms to `Decodable`, then `Array<Foo>` should automatically conform to `Decodable`. Is that not what you’re seeing in this case?

Comment: Hi, I'm getting an error when working with generics. I updated my question with an example.